# I want to customize a link, it does not work. Where is my error?

Tags: html, css

Basically i just want to put a button around a link and this is my code:

```css
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ff523b;
    color: black;
    padding: 8px 30px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<a href= "#" class="btn">Explore Now</a>
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens when i add the CSS part. The link gets added in right part, but doing anything in CSS won't change the look of it. Where is my error please?

Comment: Your code is correct, check again if your CSS is properly linked to your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS must be inside the <style> tag, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
   .btn{
   display: inline-block;
   background: #ff523b;
   color: black;
   padding: 8px 30px;
   margin: 30px 0;
   border-radius: 40px;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Explore Now</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

... or referenced with a link to a stylesheet (e.g styles.css) with your css styles

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Explore Now</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Note: In this example, the stylesheet is supposed to live in the same directory of your html file.

Comment: Hi, it is in the CSS file and all other CSS codes work. I have no clue why it is not doing anything.

Comment: Okay thank you, it's working now. I had some random text in between, had to delete it. Now it works. The code was fine there was just some text i had to delete. But i don't like about Html that it doesnt red line errors like this.